# I can't send emails or respond to emails. I click "send" and nothing happens.

Tags: gmail

I can't send my emails.  I click "send" and nothing happens.  I cannot respond to emails, either.  I type in my response and click "send" and again, nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with a "send mail as" address (using Gmail as an SMTP client).  I also noticed that it said "saving..." but never saved to drafts.  If I switched to a different FROM address, it would save.

I solved this by **refreshing the Gmail tab**.

Answer (score 1):

If it happens on gmail, and you use an app to send/receive, it might be because you use a "less secure app" (eg. a depreciated email smartphone app)

Try to enable less secure app access in https://myaccount.google.com

(If you have several gmail account, check if this page is connected to the right account).

In my case it was OFF, I could download the mail (which is weird) but could not send them.